# Batch Apex Class To Move One Account Opportunities and Cases To Another Account

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

Now I have 2 Accounts, Suppose Say Account1 and Account2 .Account1 is having 2 opporotunities and 3 cases Now I want to reparent all these opportunities and cases to account2 using BatchApex.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine you build a visualforce page with 2 lookup fields called "fromAccount" and "toAccount".

**Handle thousands of related records**

*This is your controller class*

```
class SwitchAccountController
{
    String fromAccountId;
    String toAccountId;

    // action Button
    public void executeBatch()
    {
        if(fromAccountId != null && toAccountId != null && fromAccountId != toAccountId)
        {
            // start batches
            Database.executeBatch(new SwitchAccountBatch(fromAccountId, toAccountId, 'Opportunity'));
            Database.executeBatch(new SwitchAccountBatch(fromAccountId, toAccountId, 'Case'));
        }
    }
}
```

*This is your batch class*

```
global class SwitchAccountBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    String toAccountId;
    String fromAccountId;
    String query;

    global SwitchAccountBatch(String aFromAccountId, String aToAccountId, String objectName) {
            toAccountId = aToAccountId;
            fromAccountId = aFromAccountId;
            String query = 'SELECT AccountId FROM '+objectName+' WHERE ID =\''+fromAccountId+'\'';

    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
        for(sObject s : scope)
        {
            s.put('AccountId', toAccountId);
        }
        update scope;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }

}
```

**Handle hundreds of records**

```
class SwitchAccountController
{
    public void switchAccounts(String fromAccountId, String toAccountId)
    {
        if(fromAccountId != null && toAccountId != null && fromAccountId != toAccountId)
        {
            // query cases
            List<Case>cases = [SELECT ID, AccountID FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :fromAccountId];

            // query opps
            List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT ID, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :fromAccountId];

            // change account id

            for(Case c: cases)
            {
                c.AccountId = toAccountId;
            }
            for(Opportunity o : opportunities)
            {
                c.AccountId = toAccountId;
            }
            if(cases.size() > 0)
            update cases;
            if(opportunities.size() > 0)
            update opportunities;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bujji By using batches you are able to move more than 10k opportunities and cases from one account to another.

Comment: @Deckart How to write 2 quireys in start and to send execute() method.

Comment: @Bujji You can do it in a single class (without a batch) if your account is related to hundreds not thousands of records (cases, opportunities).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Deckert.It's Working fine Instead of calling BatchApex 2 times But I want to get all Cases and Opportunities by passing fromAccId and ToAccoId in Start method and To pass and execute at execute() method.Is it possible ? or directly we can Write Query inside of execute() method.